# Play / Stop buttons

Tags: angular, angular-material

I need to write a feature that will render multiple audio files and for each there will be a play button.
When individual button clicked, the audio is played and the button will turn to stop icon. How can I control each button individually in same component?

[Here is an example I am working with](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-re3dmu)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to have a list it's better.

Try this :

**TS :**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {

  playlist = [
    {name: 'music1', play : false},
    {name: 'music2', play : false},
    {name: 'music3', play : false}
  ]

  togglePlay(music :any) {
    music.play = !music.play;
  }
}
```

**HTML :**

```
<button *ngFor="let music of playlist" (click)="togglePlay(music)" mat-icon-button>
  <mat-icon class="blue"> {{ music.play ? 'stop_circle_outline' : 'play_circle_outline'}}</mat-icon>
</button>
```